# error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘float’ and ‘float *’)

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to make a program in which I can read a file with animals weight and calculate the weight average. I got this error while trying to compile. Does anyone knows why?

funciones.c

```
#include "header.h"

float count_animals(FILE *file){

        float total_animals = 0;
        char word[20];

        while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) == 1){

                total_animals++;

        }

        return total_animals;

}

float sum_weight_animals(FILE *file){

        float sum_weight = 0;
        float weight[20];

        while (fscanf(file, "%f", weight) == 1){

                sum_weight += weight;

        }

        return sum_weight;

}
```

header.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXWORD 80

float count_animals(FILE *file);

float sum_weight_animals(FILE *file);
```

Just in case here's the main.c
Now I have the problem that it's not adding up the sum_weight value in sum_weight_animals function.

```
#include "header.h"

int main(){

        char WORD[MAXWORD];
        char file_name[MAXWORD];
        FILE *fileptr;

        printf("Please, enter a file name: ");
        scanf("%s", file_name);

        printf("Reading file %s...\n", file_name);
        fileptr = fopen(file_name, "r");

        if(fileptr == NULL){

                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: The file '%s' doesn't exists\n", file_name);
                return 1;

        }

        float total_animals = count_animals(fileptr);

        if (total_animals > 0){

                printf("There're %.2f animals.\n", total_animals);

        }
        else{

                fprintf(stderr, "WARNING: File not found or it's empty\n");

        }



        float total_sum = sum_weight_animals(fileptr);

        if (total_sum > 0){

                printf("The sum of all animal's weight is %.2f [kg].\n", total_sum);

        }
        else{

                fprintf(stderr,"WARNING: File not found or it's empty\n");

        }


        fclose(fileptr);

        return 0;

}
```

When ex Makefile, it compiles correctly and the first function works fine, but the second one doesn't and it gives me the **WARNING: File not found or it's empty\n** that I put on main.c

Comment: "error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘float’ and ‘float *’)" This is kind of self-explanatory. `sum_weight += weight;` doesn't work since `weight` is an array.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```c
float weight[20];
```

with

```c
float weight;
```

and replace

```c
fscanf(file, "%f", weight)
```

with

```c
fscanf(file, "%f", &weight)
```

---

Explanation:

```c
sum_weight += weight;
```

is basically equivalent to

```c
sum_weight = sum_weight + weight;
```

Let's look at the right-hand side, `sum_weight + weight`.

- `sum_weight` is a `float`.
- `weight` is an array of 20 `float` elements.

What does it mean to add a float and an array together? Nothing, that's what. This makes no sense.

You assigned a value to `weight[0]`, and this is the value you want to add. Not `weight`.

But why is `weight` an array in the first place? As the name implies, it's only used to store one weight. You only ever assign to `weight[0]`. So it makes no sense to use an array.

Comment: Thank you it now works! One more question, the sum_weight function is not working correctly, its not adding up sum_weight value.

Comment: Be more specific. What does it do that's wrong?

Comment: I updated the question, please if you can review it. Thank you very much

Comment: You read to the end of the file in `count_animals`, then you try to read some more in `sum_weight_animals`. As the message says, there's nothing left to read.

Comment: I corrected it. It's ok if I close the file and then open it again? Because that's what I did and now it did make the sum. Thank u for your help!

Comment: Well, you could do that. You could also use fseek to "rewind" the file. But why read the file twice at all? You could count the animals while calculating their average weight.